# cannot connect google cloud sql using jdbc via google apps script library

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have a question about jdbc issue via google apps script(gas).

```
var aUrl = "jdbc:google:rdbms:[cloud sql instance id]/[dbname]";
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(aUrl, username, pass);
```

*[cloud sql instance id]... its written in developer console. the format is like "meaningless letters:instance name".

*[dbname]... mysql database name.

this code works well while project owner execution, but once it executed from another user after making it library, it says like "**cannot connect to database. check connection strings, username, password (line xx, file "foo", project"CommonLibrary")**"

Does anyone know why?

### The simplified project structure is like below:

#### Project "CommonLibrary" includes two gs files

DBAccess.gs

```
function connectionToDatabase()
{
  var aUrl = "jdbc:google:rdbms:[cloud sql instance id]/[dbname]";
  return Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(aUrl, username, pass);
}
```

fooDBAccess.gs

```
function selectFoo()
{
  var conn = connectionToDatabase();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM foos');
  var foos = [];
  -- do something with results -- 
  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  return foos;
}
```

#### project "bar" includes one gs file

*project "CommonLibrary" is identified with "Common"

```
function plotFoos()
{
  var foos = Common.selectFoo();
}
```

*got error on `var foos = Common.selectFoo();` mentioned above.

P.S.

I already authorised 8 OAuth Scopes required by the script:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.storage
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice
```

Then

- The library is on developer mode.
- I deployed "CommonLibrary" as web app
  (execute the app as project owner, anyone within xxx.org has access to the app).
- I tried connection samples below once, but doesn't work. the error saying '//' cannot use.
  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: this issue is similar to mine. so it might be a bug...
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3695&can=1&q=jdbc&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Comment: got solved a long ago, so I just add comment for someone like me.
the problem is you didn't permitted IP adresses google cloud sql uses, which is listed on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).
64.18.0.0/20  
64.233.160.0/19  
... and so on.